# Javascript - remove a sentence from an element (w/o id/class) but leave the rest of the content

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a greasemonkey script which I will use at one website to fill in the form. I don't own the website. Main purpose is to remove the 'clutter' of 'informational texts' and only leave input/select fields.

Problem here is that paragraph doesn't have a class or id attached to it. It does have a sentance which I want to remove, BUT paragraphs also has an INPUT along with that sentance inside the same paragraph. I want INPUT to stay but sentence to be removed.

The form at the website has multiple paragraphs with the same 'issue', so it is not one 'issue' per one form. Also sentences are different per different paragraphs. Here is a simplified version of how it looks like:

```
<div id="shop_info">
    <p>
        32. Enter the store's name/logo
        <input id="store_name" type="text" name="store_name">
    </p>

    <p>
        33. Enter the store's phone number
        <input id="store_phone" type="text" name="store_phone">
    </p>
</div>
```

^ In the above example I need these sentences removed:
**32. Enter the store's name/logo**
**33. Enter the store's phone number**

So, after the script is done its work, it should look like this:

```
<div id="shop_info">
    <p>
        <input id="store_name" type="text" name="store_name">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input id="store_phone" type="text" name="store_phone">
    </p>
</div>
```

...and if there is a way to get INPUTS out of paragraphs (which are now not-needed), it would be best if it can end like this:

```
<div id="shop_info">
    <input id="store_name" type="text" name="store_name">

    <input id="store_phone" type="text" name="store_phone">
</div>
```

...but I will be happy even with the first solution (if INPUTs stay inside paragraphs, I just need these sentences gone).

I looked around, but the code examples that I have found didn't worked, because most of the solutions 'search' for a single text word and not the whole sentences. I pasted just a simplified code of that page. There are many more paragraphs which have INPUT nested inside them.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I've checked some codes that some of you provided. For some reason, even if it works at codepen or other 'script testing' sites, the code doesn't work once I implemented it in my greasemonkey script. I have decided to show you how the form looks like on the website itself. Its an Amzn site, for microworkers. Here is the page with form itself:

[page in question at Amzn microworkers website](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mgw.ourcart.com/eae764c5-7b6e-4062-ac13-b306eb3566c9.html)

Here is the imgur gallery that has 3 images:

[imgur gallery with 3 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdgpO.jpg)

1st image: how the whole page looks like
2nd image: what I got till now
3rd image: what I'm trying to achieve (thats why I created this question)

I hope I've made yoru life littlebit easier now, so you can (if you want) test the codes directly at the webpage itself.

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You could use `jQuery.contains` to match the text, or a JavaScript polyfill for the equivalent functionality.

Comment: @fubar: Thanks for your suggestion. I remember that among bunch of codes that I've tried, it was something with 'jQuery.contains', but it didn't worked. I guess its because I implemented it the wrong way. Since I'm a newb, could you give me an example that apply to my html code above, please?

Comment: *" I don't own the website."* thank you for mentioning that, most OPs say that later on after an inordinate amount of time has been wasted. You can't access the website's content in an iframe if you don't own the website. What exactly is your intention? Did you just want a copy of the form without the content? Do you need to clear the form and use it from the iframe?

Comment: @zer00ne: hey zer00ne, thanks for your comment. Yes, I've noticed that OPs forget to mantion that important information while I was trying to find solution for my 'issue' among other code questions (and examples). Thats why I said up front that I don't own the website. I also edited my post and provided the page I'm trying to modify. And also provided an imgur gallery which shows what I have already achieved, and what I want to achive with this code-request here. I hope that such information can help all of you.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet may be useful, Have added comments to describe the steps

```js
//get the parent element by the id
let getElem = document.getElementById("shop_info");
// get all the paragraph using querySelectorAll &
//iterate over it using forEach;
getElem.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(item) {
  // get the input element, this will be appended later
  let getInput = item.querySelector('input');
  // empty the p element
  item.innerHTML = "";
  // append the input back to the paragraph
  item.appendChild(getInput);
})
```

```html
<div id="shop_info">
  <p>
    32. Enter the store's name/logo
    <input id="store_name" type="text" name="store_name">
  </p>

  <p>
    33. Enter the store's phone number
    <input id="store_phone" type="text" name="store_phone">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: the original question was edited after this answer, If you want to remove the `p` elements also then get all the input first and remove the `p` in same way, then iterate over the `input` collection and append it back to DOM

Comment: @brk: thanks for providing your code. I edited becaues I've made some grammar mistakes, and also, yes I added it would be 'best' without inputs being out of paragraphs, but any solution which will just remove these sentances from paragraphs would be great! I tested your code and it doesn't work. I don't know why, cause it looked nice with all the comments you left with every line of code.

Comment: @Daniel Tate: I appreciate that brk provided his code so fast. I like how his code looks like. Problem is...it doesn't work at my end. So... I can't mark it as a 'correct answer' because it doesn't work for me, for the website I need it to work.

Comment: check console and share the error, better will be if you can share the actual dom

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with jQuery

```
$(function(){
    var $inputs = $('#shop_info input');
    $('#shop_info').empty();
    $inputs.each(function(k, v){
        $(this).appendTo('#shop_info').wrap('<p/>');
    });
});
```

here's the example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqKgWy

Comment: Thanks for your code. I checked that codepen link you provided. It does work there. Unfortunately, when implemented in my greasemonkey script, it doesn't work. It does nothing to a website page that I'm trying to modify.

Comment: I've edited my OP. Can you check the links I've left in OP (under **EDIT**), please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to clean up `<form>` elements, you want to remove all non-`<input>` and non-`<select>` elements from them.

If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```js
var holder = [];
$("input, select, button").each(function(){
   holder.push({parentForm: $(this).parents("form"), elm: $(this)});
}).detach();
$("form>").remove();
holder.forEach(elm => {
  elm.parentForm.append(elm.elm);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div id="shop_info">
      <p>
          32. Enter the store's name/logo
          <input id="store_name" type="text" name="store_name">
      </p>

      <p>
          33. Enter the store's phone number
          <input id="store_phone" type="text" name="store_phone">
      </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

What this does is to first go through all `input`, `select` and `button` elements, keep track of what their parent `form` element is, detach them. Then, remove all elements from the forms and attach back the `input`, `select` and `button`elements.

Comment: thanks for your code. Unfortunately it doesn't work for the page I need it to work. I edited my OP and posted direct link to the website where page (with form) is located. I also posted imgur gallery with 3 images. Top being how page looks without modification, 2nd one, how it looks like with modifications so far, and the bottom one is what I'm trying to achieve. Can you take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my post with new information. I've also included the link to the page itself that I'm trying to modify. At the imgur gallery, last image (3rd from the top) is what I'm trying to achieve with the code that I'm seeking to find from your answers on this (OP) question here.